# Generating a list of events in a Delphi/BCB Project

Tags: delphi, events, c++builder

I would like to generate a list of events and methods assigned to them in a given BCB project. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this in a 100% reliable way. But maybe it's enough to just scan all the *.dfm's in your project folder for lines starting with "  On".

Answer (score 1):

There are DFM parser code available on the net.

http://www.felix-colibri.com/papers/colibri_utilities/dfm_parser/dfm_parser.html

FWIW, event is simply a property with method type.

Answer (score 0):

I have just recently written a DFM file parser myself. My use case was to load a form and extract and replace some binary information from it. The library is written in Go, it is well-tested with RAD Studio source code and our own production code.

https://github.com/gonutz/dfm

You can use the parser, walk the tree in memory and generate what you need from it.